# Vuex: Why do we write mutations, actions and getters in uppercase?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm wondering why do we write the function name of mutations, actions and getters in uppercase? Where does this convention come from?

```
export default {
  SOME_MUTATION (state, payload) {

  },

  ANOTHER_MUTATION (state, payload) {

  },
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a [long standing coding style](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/319688/what-is-the-history-for-naming-constants-in-all-uppercase) to write constants in all uppercase.

From the Vuex [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html):

> It is a commonly seen pattern to use constants for mutation types in
>   various Flux implementations. This allows the code to take advantage
>   of tooling like linters, and putting all constants in a single file
>   allows your collaborators to get an at-a-glance view of what mutations
>   are possible in the entire application

So, it's really just following a long standing tradition of naming constants in uppercase for the most part. It's not required.

> Whether to use constants is largely a preference - it can be helpful in large projects with many developers, but it's totally optional if you don't like them

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation.

Comment: this answer is in fact misleading as explained in @Pwdr answer below

Comment: @pawel Help me understand. Do you think it's misleading because you think the answer says typing the names in all uppercase makes them constant?

Comment: @Bert I believe that attached parts of Vuex documentation are not indicating that mutation function names should be written in uppercase. In fact, examples on the page you link show mutation names written in lowercase, e.g. 'increment'. It's true that writing constants in uppercase is a popular coding style but that's another story. I believe the correct answer to the OP question would be: "we are not writing mutation function names in uppercase".

Comment: @pawel I can see your point.I read the question differently. Specifically the question asks "Where does this convention come from?" and not "should I do it this way?". I think pwdr's answer is more to the advantages of defining the names as constants, where it doesn't really matter whether they are upper case or not.

Comment: @Bert Fair point, maybe Pwdr's reply does not specifically answer the OP's question. However, while your answer is more on subject of why people would do this, my point is that there is no such convention suggested in the docs and that this "convention" is more of a misunderstanding.

Comment: Just to be clear SOME_MUTATION in OP is not a constant it is a function. Making it perfectly possible to overwrite it. In general I hardly see JS developers using ALLCAPS for constants.

Answer (score 33):

The accepted answer by [Bert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38065/bert) is a bit misleading. Constant variables are traditionally written in all caps, but the way it is used in the question does not make it a constant.

> This allows the code to take advantage of tooling like linters

The official Vue.js documentation [recommends using all caps](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#using-constants-for-mutation-types), but as variables in an additional file. This makes it possible to require the available function names in other files and use auto-complete.

*mutation-types.js:*

```
export const SOME_MUTATION = 'SOME_MUTATION'
```

*store.js:*

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { SOME_MUTATION } from './mutation-types'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { ... },
  mutations: {
    // we can use the ES2015 computed property name feature
    // to use a constant as the function name
    [SOME_MUTATION] (state) {
      // mutate state
    }
  }
})
```

Please note the different writing-style here (*computed property name* with square brackets):

```
[SOME_MUTATION] (state) { }
```

---

If you just write the function names in all upper case (i.e. `SOME_MUTATION(state) { }`) the only benefit is a mere visual one (to separate Vuex functions from others), but in my opinion this does not make much sense. Stick to the one with computed property name (`[SOME_MUTATION] (state)`) to get all the benefits.